# File /etc/resolv.conf deleted on every reboot, why or what?

Tags: networking, fedora, networkmanager, dhcp, resolv.conf

<strike>I am having an issue where DHCP (I though as I read in other similar topics) is clearing the `/etc/resolv.conf` file on each boot.</strike> I am not sure about how to deal with this since the post I have found ([1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/what-overwrites-etc-resolv-conf-on-every-boot), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31608/etc-resolv-conf-changes-during-reboot) and some others) are for Debian based distros or other but not Fedora.

This is the output of `ifcfg-enp0s31f6` so for sure is DHCP:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s31f6 
HWADDR=C8:5B:76:1A:8E:55
TYPE=Ethernet
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=no
IPV6_AUTOCONF=no
IPV6_DEFROUTE=no
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=enp0s31f6
UUID=0af812a3-ac8e-32a0-887d-10884872d6c7
ONBOOT=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=no
IPV6_PEERROUTES=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
```

In the other side I don't know if Network Manager is doing something else around this.

**Update: Content of NetworkManager.conf** (I have removed the comments since are useless)

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
#plugins=ifcfg-rh,ibft
dns=none

[logging]
#domains=ALL
```

Can I get some help with this? It's annonying be setting up the file once and once on every reboot.

**UPDATE 2**

After a month I'm still having the same issue where file gets deleted by "something".

Here is the steps I did follow in order to make a fresh test:

- Reboot the PC
- After PC gets restarted open a terminal and try to `ping` Google servers of course without success:

  ```
  $ ping google.com
  ping: google.com: Name or service not known
  ```
- Check the network configuration were all seems to be fine:

  ```
  $ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s31f6 
  NAME=enp0s31f6
  ONBOOT=yes
  HWADDR=C8:5B:76:1A:8E:55
  MACADDR=C8:5B:76:1A:8E:55
  UUID=0af812a3-ac8e-32a0-887d-10884872d6c7
  BOOTPROTO=static
  PEERDNS=no
  DNS1=8.8.8.8
  DNS2=8.8.4.4
  DNS3=192.168.1.10
  NM_CONTROLLED=yes
  IPADDR=192.168.1.66
  NETMASK=255.255.255.0
  BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
  GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
  TYPE=Ethernet
  DEFROUTE=yes
  IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
  IPV6INIT=no
  ```
- Restart the `network` service:

  ```
  $ sudo service network restart
  [sudo] password for <current_user>: 
  Restarting network (via systemctl):                        [  OK  ]
  ```
- Try to `ping` Google servers again, with no success:

  ```
  $ ping google.com
  ping: google.com: Name or service not known
  ```
- Check for file `/etc/resolv.conf`:

  ```
  $ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
  cat: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
  ```
- File doesn't exists anymore - and this is the problem something is deleting it on every reboot
- Create the file and add the content of DNS:

  ```
  $ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
  ```
- Ping Google servers this time with success:

  ```
  $ ping google.com
  PING google.com (216.58.192.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
  64 bytes from mia07s35-in-f110.1e100.net (216.58.192.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=3.87 ms
  ```

Any ideas in what could be happening here?

Comment: may `PEERDNS=no` help you

Comment: @IporSircer no, I have changed the value and restart the PC, same result, no DNS information. BTW do I need to restart the PC or `service network restart` would be enough?

Comment: Try `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @GAD3R not working: `chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Which Fedora version (and Spin/Edition) are you using?

Comment: @mattdm Fedora 25 and Cinnamon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my experience, `/etc/resolv.conf` gets regenerated on boot, so any manual changes to it get reset.

To work around this, you can create `/etc/resolv.conf.head` (or `.tail` depending on which end of the file you want to add to) and insert the custom settings you want in there (usually `nameserver` changes). Then the contents of that file gets added automatically when `/etc/resolv.conf` is generated by NetworkManager (or whichever service is in charge of the file on your system).

If that doesn't work, you can modify `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` -- it stores the "default" content for `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: This workaroudnd isn't working either, I've tried and after restart `/etc/resolv.conf` is empty

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. It was soved by installing the `resolvconf` package. Since I am on Debian I can not test, but may help [this tip](https://coderwall.com/p/66kbaw/adding-entries-to-resolv-conf-on-fedora):

1. open (or create) as sudo: `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`
2. add: `prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;`

Comment: I was facing this problem for many months now. I tried different solutions. Nothing solved the problem. I just installed resolvconf package according to your suggestion. It worked!

Answer (score 2):

I think you were right on track.

It's working for me now, but I didn't do the:

```
dns=none
```

on the:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s31f6
```

After I restarted the network manager, it automatically created the resolv:

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

I rebooted and it still worked.

Answer (score 1):

"Have you tried setting your resolv.conf file to have immutability after putting whatever content you want?."

pretty sure this keeps the /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf from doing its job and your DNS never resolves anyway.  At best this is frustrating and at worst freezes things up as your computer continuously tries to run that file and establish a connection.  I think the key is in editing "/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf" instead of resolv.conf directly, as that is the file that writes to resolv.conf on reboot.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to focus on your suggestion (i.e., the last sentence of your answer) and de-emphasize your critique of the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

First You must sure `resolvconf service` active.

```
sudo service resolvconf status
```

> Active: active (exited) since

If the service `active` remove `resolvconf`:

```
sudo apt-get purge resolvconf
```

Then if after remove or this is not active or service not found:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

Then restart service:

```
sudo service resolvconf restart
```

now see the `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Must be exists:

> # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by
>   resolvconf(8)
>    # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
>    # 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
>    # run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
>
> nameserver 127.0.0.1

Comment: sudo systemctl enable resolvconf.service

to make sure it would run up after reboot

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue.
And below command solved it.

```
echo '[main]' > /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-dns-none.conf
echo 'dns=none' >> /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-dns-none.conf
systemctl reload NetworkManager
```

My environment is CentOS7.

reference
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file_configuring-and-managing-networking

Answer (score 0):

Probably NetworkManager is configuring `resolve.conf`. if you don't want that, change  `rc-manager` setting in NetworkManager.conf. See `man NetworkManager.conf`.

Comment: Nop, that's not the problem. I am reading this in docs `none: NetworkManager will not modify resolv.conf. This implies rc-managerunmanaged` and I am seeing this on `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` `[main]
dns=none`

Answer (score 0):

To prevent `resolv.conf` to be update at boot time, you should make the following changes:

Change `PEERDNS=yes` to `PEERDNS=no`

> [`PEERDNS=no`](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/21/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_Command_Line_Interface.html)
>
> This will prevent network service from updating /etc/resolv.conf with the DNS servers received from a DHCP server.

mentioned on [@Ipor Sircer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/182562/ipor-sircer) comment's

Comment: `PEERDNS` is set to `no` (see OP) now will `BOOTPROTO=static` change to static IP address instead of dynamic? If that's the case then this will not fix the issue.

Comment: @ReynierPM right

Comment: I am not using NM at all, I mean is a tool in the GUI but I never touch it, can I disable it to prevent this behavior? People using DHCP on the same office gets DNS and Internet connection so I don't know what is happening here and I am tempted to disable NM, what do you think?

Comment: @ReynierPM can you add the contents of `NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: Done, in the OP

Comment: @ReynierPM please add `NM_CONTROLLED=no` to your `ifcfg-enp0s31f6` file then test it.

Comment: That way I haven't network connectivity at all meaning no IP address or so ...

Comment: @ReynierPM  `NM_CONTROLLED=no`  to prevent NM to configure your interface. change it to `yes`  then add your dns to `NetworkManager.conf`

Comment: I am not following on your latest comment, can you add a *step by step* to your post? I am still having the problem and I've updated to Fedora 25 at this point

Comment: Also I have updated the OP with further info since I am still having the issue

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when I install Debian 9.5 with GUI today.  I do not have this problem when I install it without GUI.  Finally, I found the solution from this link https://wiki.debian.org/resolv.conf.   The DHCP started automatically even I set network manually when I was installing it.  You should disable the DHCP to stop this problem.

```
echo 'make_resolv_conf() { :; }' > /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/leave_my_resolv_conf_alone
chmod 755 /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/leave_my_resolv_conf_alone
```

If that does not solve your problem, then I added a new line in the DHCP client file.

```
vi /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

> prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;

Next, I remove the resolvconf and network-manger packages.

```
apt-get --purge remove resolvconf network-manager
```

Finally, if you still got the problem, you should setup your resolv.conf file and then lock this file by the following command.  (It does not work if your resolv.conf is a symbolic link.)

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem on

> Distributor ID:    Debian
> Description:   Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
> Release:   10
> Codename:  buster
> .

On my system I am using dnsmasq for several reasons.

Therefore the DNS for system apps is localhost aka 127.0.0.1.

In the dnsmasq then I redirect some queries to the external DNS resolvers and some I resolve locally.

Long story short:

Because I was using static IP settings for my NIC, there was no setting made for DNS servers in the GUI of NetworkManager.

Therefore no resolv.conf was being generated.

Although most services were working, some were not.

The solution to make ALL services work was to enter
127.0.0.1 as DNS Server in the GUI of NetworkManager and restart that Service.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

To me, in Debian 10, it was `connman`. Indeed:`

```
$> ls -l /etc
.. .. 
resolv.conf -> /run/connman/resolv.conf
```

I disabled `connman`, removed the file `resolv.conf` and re-created it as a regular file. After reboot finally it is still there.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried setting your resolv.conf file to have immutability after putting whatever content you want?.

You may want to use `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` or with sudo.

By doing this we avoid overwrite.

Unless it is getting deleted, it might give initial insight.