# FEDORA 25 server: can ping an ip but not a url, can't update

Tags: fedora, dns

I tried to update my home server today, but got an error

```
$ sudo dnf update
'couldn't resolve host name'
```

so I tried to ping anything in the internet, and for that I tried www.google.com, but it gives a 'System error' message,

```
$ ping www.google.com
System error
```

then tried an IP and works just fine. Googled for some info about the issue but only found 1 person with the same problem, and the problem was a file/link that was corrupt, but mine is just fine so I got stuck there.
The server was working fine so I don't know what happened.

Comment: Have you configured a DNS server? If so, can you ping it?

Comment: i didn't but in the /etc/resolv.conf there is the 208.67.222.222 and my local gateway, the first is unreachable, the second (gateway) works fine

Comment: /etc/resolv.conf should contain the address of a DNS server that can translate web to IP addresses. Try adding 8.8.8.8

Comment: added it, restarted the server (reboot) just in case, but i get the same error, it does ping 8.8.8.8 this time, but the other problems remain

Comment: Add 8.8.8.8 as the first IP address in the resolv.conf. Also try "dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com" to prove that resolution through 8.8.8.8 works correctly.

Comment: used the dig command and it answers with a list of IPs, so it seems it works well, now something changed, if i try to update it says '                          
Error: Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'updates''

Comment: the DNS was overwritten by the system it seems, changed it again to 8.8.8.8 and now it works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the default DNS wasn't working fine, changed it to 8.8.8.8 as Raman Sailopal  suggested and did a reboot, but later i found out that the DNS was overwritten to the default DNS server, changed it again and now it works fine

Comment: You should invest time to make your DNS work correctly instead of just blindly putting 8.8.8.8

Comment: i should, but sadly i don't have the time by now and i need to solve this quickly, i plan to check what went wrong, maybe my router is the problem since the DNS server is an OpenDNS server as far as i know and it's set up automatically by the system. Also i know that 8.8.8.8 is a google DNS server so its not just 'blindly' putting it, but i get what you are trying to point out, it's not 100% solved

Comment: And you are feeding your data to Google... Try 9.9.9.9 for a change :-) But you are still sending your data to someone. When you have time and if you want to learn, install a local resolver.

Comment: good point, didn't see it that way ... thanks for the suggestion i'll totally try a local resolver as soon as i have the time, and also will try 9.9.9.9, i just read it has some nice features, thanks!

Comment: As for `resolv.conf` being wiped out, see for example https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7412 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128223/211833 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323446/file-etc-resolv-conf-deleted-on-every-reboot-why-or-what

Comment: that explains why it didn't save my changes, thanks again Patrick Mevzek